# How to send data from static html page to a server?

Tags: php, google-analytics, server, analytics, cdn

Is there a way to send data from any static html page to a server like google analytics does. Basically, i want to build an app that counts the element clicks of any html file and store it to a database to be later shown to the user.

Edit: keep in mind that the database i'm sending data to and the html file that i'm requesting data from aren't hosted in the same server.

Comment: That depends on what you actually mean by "static html page". HTML markup is static by definition. You need to use javascript on the client side for _any_ action you want to perform. If you do so, then sure, the answer is "yes, there is a way".

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Ajax. It allows you to make requests to other pages using Javascript without reloading the page.

Comment: i mean by static html page that the html file and the database are hosted in different servers.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  what if the html file and the database i'm sending files to aren't hosted in the same server?

Comment: Just search for "Ajax Cross Origin" or "Ajax CORS" and you will find solutions for that.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use for that AJAX, Iframe or Tracking Pixel. I think that the best solution would be to use Tracking Pixel.

> A tracking pixel (also called 1x1 pixel or pixel tag) is a graphic
>   that is loaded when a user visits a website or opens an email and is
>   used to track certain user activities. A tracking pixel can also be
>   used to acquire statistical data for online marketing, web analytics,
>   or email marketing. This information can then be used for different
>   purposes through log file analysis.

Its mean that you just make a HTTP GET request into your tracking system. For example you can add:

```
<img src="http://example.com/tracker.php?target=page1&t=12154565612" />
```

In this way, you can able to pass any data to a tracking server via GET parameters (do not forget to add the time stamp as one of the parameters, it will let you escape the caching).

Comment: Since the OP is looking for something similar to Google Analytics, I think forms are out of the question. Your answer should really contain an example and not just a link. If the link changes, this answer becomes useless for future visitors. Add examples in your question and just add links for reference/more in-depth reading. (And no, I'm not the dowvoter)

Comment: Updated my answer